# Observable combination in NgRx effect - Dispatching an invalid action

Tags: javascript, rxjs, ngrx

I am trying to make an effect that does quite a bunch of stuff, and returns a success/fail action.

Here is a simplified version of what I am doing:

```js
UploadSolidModel$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.UploadSolidRequest>(featureActions.ActionTypes.UploadSolidRequest),
    switchMap((action) =>
      // 1) return an observable with elevation
      this.altimeterService.getElevation()
      // 2) use the above result to make some change and dispatch an API call that return an observable
        .pipe(
          switchMap((elevation) =>
            this.dataService.uploadSolid()
          )
        )
      // 3.a) use the response from the previous api call to dispatch a success/fail effect
        .pipe(
          map((response) => {
            return new ActionSuccess;
          }),
      // 3) 3.b) use the failure of the api call to dispatch failure effect
          catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            return of(new featureActions.UploadSolidFailed({ error: error.message }));
          })
        )
    )
```

The problem I have is that NgRx is telling me my effect is dispatching an invalid action.
My chain must be wrong, but I tried to fix it and couldn't find a way to make this work.

Comment: If the response in 3a comes from `dataService.uploadSolid` then you have the `pipe` at the wrong level, it should be chained from `uploadSolid`

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the constructor of the action at 3a. It should return an action instance instead.

```
// notice the `()`
return new ActionSuccess()
```